# How to program mouse buttons in Ubuntu to change the scroll

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scroll, mouse, mousewheel

I have a mouse with vertical and horizontal scroll wheels. I want to use the thumb wheel (currently programmed to scroll horizontally) to scroll vertically instead, as I get pain in my index fingers.

I've spent a few hours trying to solve this. The best tutorial I've found is here:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/map-mouse-on-linux/

I've managed to copy a xorg.config file to /etc/X11/ and then I've entered the command:
`xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 6 7 4 5 8 9 10"` and switched 6&7 and 4&5 scroll functions.

When I enter  `xmodmap -pp` into the CLI, I get:

```
    Physical        Button
     Button          Code
        1              1
        2              2
        3              3
        4              6
        5              7
        6              4
        7              5
        8              8
        9              9
       10             10
```

But when I try the mouse wheels they're still doing the same thing. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the tutorial I was following was outdated. The solution is to use xinput:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/492744/how-do-i-automatically-remap-buttons-on-my-mouse-at-startup

Comment: Hi, JimmyTheCode. I want to do the same as you, also because of pain in my hand. You might be in a position to answer my related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433701/swap-vert-horiz-scrolling-remapping-buttons-has-no-effect. I'm already basing my solution on the answer you've linked to. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mehmet, I'm afraid I couldn't work it out either. It looks like I got as far as you have and then gave up. Very best of luck! I'd be curious to hear how you manage it if you succeed!